# Meaning of “ハートは赤く染まる”

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics

What does ハートは赤く染まる mean?  It’s from a love song about someone being completely smitten by another.

I know the literal translation is “(my) heart is stained red” but what is the meaning of this phrase?

Answer (score 2):

> 「ハートは赤{あか}く染{そ}まる」

Unless the context proves otherwise, it should mean something along the lines of:

> "My heart turns red."

or

> "My heart flushes."

To me, "stain" would sound quite strange.

Comment: Does it have another meaning along the lines of having fallen in love or something similar? The lyrics seem to imply that.

Comment: @Noob You seem to believe this phrase has a special meaning, but it doesn't. This is neither an established set phrase nor a reference to something well-known. Of course this may suggest love if you believe the context says so, but no one can confirm it.

Comment: @naruto I had thought it might be an idiom or something like that. Thank you for the clarification.